# Sencha plugin problems with IntelliJ

Tags: extjs, intellij-idea

I am new to Sencha and Intellij.  I downloaded the sencha plugin, but it tells me it won't run because of dependencies on JavaScript and com.intellij.css.  Where/how to I get those into the IDE ?

Comment: read this link : https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?303659-Sencha-IntelliJ-plugin-configuration

Answer (score 0):

The plugin will only work in IDEA Ultimate, because the Javascript and CSS plugins are [not included in the Community edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

Alternatively, it should work with other IDEs that contain these plugins (RubyMine, WebStorm etc).